# Run cargo build-bpf output error: no such command: `+solana`

Tags: solana-program

I start a hello_world demo.Run cargo build-bpf but output error :

```
cargo build-bpf
info: uninstalling toolchain 'solana'
info: toolchain 'solana' uninstalled
error: no such command: `+solana`

    Cargo does not handle `+toolchain` directives.
    Did you mean to invoke `cargo` through `rustup` instead?
```

I guess it's because I didn't set Solana as the default chain tool, so I set it up

```
rustup show
Default host: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
solana (default)

active toolchain
----------------

solana (default)
rustc 1.68.0-dev
```

But it doesn't work and output the same error.This my CLI version

```
solana --version
solana-cli 1.17.9 (src:daf37308; feat:1428472342, client:SolanaLabs)
```

Comment: Maybe helps: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8396/run-cargo-build-bpf-output-error-no-such-command-solana